# PHP server does not get the $.ajax request from jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Hi I am calling the following javascript function to send some data to 
a php server. But the server does not receive the data:

```
function sendData()
{
   var obj = new Object();
   obj.id = "001";
   obj.len = "7";

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php.php",
      data: JSON.stringify(obj)
      }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
}
```

this is my php code:

```
<?php   
   if (!empty($_POST))
   {
      echo $_POST['id'];
   }
   else
      echo "no data"  
?>
```

Can some one please let me know where I am making the mistake. I just
could not figure it out!

Comment: Is there any error thrown at the browser console? You can monitor it using a debugging tool or by writing a `fail` callback for the request?

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify`, send your object.

Comment: as @undefined suggests ..send object... current approach has no key/ value pairs...just a JSON string... so `$_POST['id']` is not defined. jQuery will form encode the object

Comment: in your ajax obj, add a 'success' and 'error' function, and log the error

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes JSON.stringify removal did fix it. @Arun from server I was getting the else scho "no data" as if these was no data posted on the server - it was empty! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this causes the problem

```
data: JSON.stringify(obj)
```

and change it to

```
 data: obj
```

**from the JQuery docs:**

> **data**
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. **Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs**. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting

reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Wow it did work. I spent hours to figure it out. Thanks a lot. Did it go to the server as JSON or javascript object?

Comment: you will receive it as a PHP array `$_POST` where keys is the same of the JSON object keys you sent

Comment: Thanks Mahan. Really appreciate your time and help! :-)

Comment: well don't forget to check my answer =)

Comment: Yes I did but I am too small to check! I do not have at leat 15 reputations to check an answer :-(

Comment: ahh ok that's fine =) well welcome to stackoverflow, enjoy learning!!

Comment: Oh I am allowed to check my questions. I did it but cannot vote an answer up till in am 15 "years old"!